# When root opens crontab Vim is used although Nano is set as the default editor. Why might this be?

Tags: linux, cron, sudo, vim, nano

**Environment:** CentOS 8

**Question:** When I enter `sudo crontab -e` it opens in Vim.  However Nano is set as the default editor and for every other type of file it is used as expected.  Why might this be? Is there a way around this?

**Background:** I followed these steps to make Nano the default editor.

```
# nano /root/.bashrc
```

I added these lines and saved the file.

```
export EDITOR='nano'
export VISUAL='nano'
```

This is what the entire file consists of.

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

export EDITOR='nano'
export VISUAL='nano'
```

I used this command to make the change active.

```
# source /root/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/root/.bashrc` is executed only if a shell is started under the root account. Executing a command with `sudo` usually does not invoke a shell so the file is not used.

`sudo` would keep the environment variable `EDITOR` if it is set for the calling user. So that is the solution to your problem:

```
EDITOR='nano' sudo crontab -e
```

Comment: @myNewAccount It makes no sense to use `sudo` in `/root/.bashrc` (unless changing to a non-root user). And why would you have `crontab` run on every shell startup? You can put `export EDITOR='nano'` in the `~/.bashrc` of the user which calls `sudo` (then your old `sudo` command line should work as expected).

Comment: Many systems install sudo with `Defaults env_reset` which wipes all environment variables, including `$EDITOR`. That means merely setting `EDITOR=nano` would be insufficient. In such a case, add `Defaults env_keep += "EDITOR"` in `/etc/sudoers` or in a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` to ensure that you are keeping that variable.